# Is there a limit on the number of records an Azure Logic App can get from Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, azure-logic-apps

A Logic Apps query only returns 200 of about 400 expected SalesForce records.

This SOQL query returns almost 400 records when run in SalesForce:

`SELECT id,origin_city__c, origin_state__c, orig_zip__c , Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c, Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c, dest_city__c, dest_state__c, dest_zip__c, Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c, Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c, Weight__c, max_pay__c FROM shipment__c WHERE Equipment_Category__c = 'VAN' AND Stops_Display__c = '2' AND Record_Type_Name__c = 'TL' AND status__c = 'Available' AND Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c >= TOMORROW AND Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c <= NEXT_N_DAYS:31`

However, the equivalent Logic Apps step (below) only returns the first 200. Is there some implicit limit I need to learn?

```
                "queries": {
                    "$filter": "Equipment_Category__c EQ 'VAN' AND Stops_Display__c EQ '2' AND Record_Type_Name__c EQ 'TL' AND status__c EQ 'Available' AND Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c GE @{addDays(startOfDay(utcNow()),1)} AND Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c LE @{addDays(startOfDay(utcNow()),31)}",
                    "$select": "origin_city__c, origin_state__c, orig_zip__c , Pickup_ScheduledStartDateTime__c, Pickup_ScheduledEndDateTime__c,\ndest_city__c, dest_state__c, dest_zip__c, Delivery_ScheduledStartDateTime__c, Delivery_ScheduledEndDateTime__c, Weight__c, max_pay__c",
                    "$skip": 0,
                    "$top": 1000
                }
```

Comment: Is the integration running as sysadmin / same user that runs the query manually? You may be a victim of sharing rules, some rows being not visible to your azure app. You could also experiment with removing filters until it starts to return more, maybe bug in whatever is translating your syntax to soql? And that manual soql is "normal", right? You didn't use extra tricks like "query all" to include stuff in recycle bin?

Answer (score 1):

By default, LogicApps return only the first page of data. If you go to Options and turn on Paging, then LogicApps will continue to call the connector iteratively, paging the data in until all of the requested data has been processed. So, [I fixed it in the Pagings settings on my step.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIBrD.png) I expanded paging to 600 records to be on the safe side.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).